# animation continues after elapsing animationDuration

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, core-animation

I want to make an animation within a specific duration. My code is below:

```
- (void)animate{

NSArray *myImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"04.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"05.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"06.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"07.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"08.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"09.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],
                     nil];


faceImage.animationImages = myImages;
faceImage.animationDuration = 4.0;
faceImage.animationRepeatCount = 4;

[faceImage startAnimating];
```

}

Now the problem is after elapsing animationDuration, animationRepeatCount continues for a few more seconds! But i want to make my animationRepeatCount within that 4 seconds. After 4 seconds my animation should stop! What is the problem i am doing my code? Or, how can i solve this?

Comment: So you can make animation Duration to 1

Comment: This should take 16 seconds, 4 seconds for each repeat of the sequence. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: So as per @rdelmar and your requirement you can do like : faceImage.animationDuration = 1.0;
faceImage.animationRepeatCount = 4;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code should be :

```
- (void)animate
{
   NSArray *myImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"04.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"05.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"06.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"07.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"08.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"09.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],
                     nil];


   faceImage.animationImages = myImages;
   faceImage.animationDuration = 1.0;
   faceImage.animationRepeatCount = 4;

   [faceImage startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you go any further you need to understand following:

> animationDuration;         // for one cycle of images. default is number of images * 1/30th of a second (i.e. 30 fps)

That means the animation duration you set is for one cycle of image. So now if you want to repete animation 4 times in 4 seconds. Set `animationDuration` 1 Second.

Also you can manually `stopAnimating` in any circumstances if you need;

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace your awful array initialization with something like this:

```
int imageCount = ...;
int *longestStringLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", imageCount - 1].length;
NSMutableArray *myImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    while(filename.length < longestStringLength) {

        filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%@", filename];
    }
    filename = [filename stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
}
```

For the second, check your current animation duration and divide its variable by 4 if it is necessary.